# I need to refresh page to display wp_get_current_user() : why?

Tags: plugin-development, cache

I am creating a WP plugin.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
print_r($current_user);
```

When I first login to WP, nothing is displayed.

**I need to REFRESH the page so wp_get_current_user() is displayed.**

(I do not use any WP cache plugin.)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your plugin code is executed much earlier, than wp-login.php. You can read about WordPress loading sequence [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-wordpress-actually-works-behind-the-scenes-infographic/), for example.

To behave properly, your code must be executed in 'wp_login' hook:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'wp_login_action', 10, 2 );
function wp_login_action( $user_login, $user ) {
    current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    print_r($current_user);
}
```